# Android AutocompleteTextView Adapter for asynchronous API with callbacks

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I working on implementation of autocomplete suggestion via some REST API (it's actually Nokia Here Geocoder Autocomplete API, but its not so important). I write custom adapter for `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
public class GeoAutocompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            // obtain some autocomplete data

            filterResults.values = res;
            filterResults.count = res.size();
            return filterResults;
        }
        //...
      }
//...
}
```

As far as I understand, section `"obtain some autocomplete data"` run in thread pool. If I obtain results for autocomplete in synchronous way - its working. For example, I can use `HttpURLConnection` and `InputStream` - all synchronous blocking call works pretty well here.

But what if I need to call some API here, which operate in asynchronous way, like via Callback \ Listener?

How can I call something like this inside performFiltering ?

```
request.execute(
        new ResultListener<List<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<Location> locations, ErrorCode errorCode) {

            }
        //...
        }
```

How can I postpone returning from methods while callback not give me an results?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671404/autocompletetextview-not-displaying-result-even-when-the-arrayadapter-is-updated

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185785/4685284. Only need to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 6):

You can make the thread to wait for results from async API in performFiltering method till response is received.

Since method performFiltering runs in a worker thread, you can make the thread wait for results as shown below, lockTwo is object and placeResults boolean indicator.

```
        while (!placeResults) {
            synchronized (lockTwo) {
                try {
                    lockTwo.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

In the callback or listener, once response is processed, add notify as shown below.

```
                placeResults = true;
                synchronized (lockTwo) {
                    lockTwo.notifyAll();
                }
```

For more information you can check places auto search example at http://www.zoftino.com/google-places-auto-complete-android